Android dot folder (hidden folder) is not showing in windows
I make a folder in my android device under that i have some files and .private folder ("dot" folder usually hidden in an android) under that hidden folder i have many important files. When i connect my android device to pc through usb cable and tranfer the outer folder through cut & paste the hidden folder is not showing in my pc and also in my android device.
I checked the show hidden files on my pc but it does not work.

Windows accesses Android using MTP protocol (on Android side called "File Transfer").
In this mode Windows shows you all files and folders Android exposes via MTP.
If dot files and folders are not shown, then this is caused by Android and can not be changed on Windows side.
If you want to view or edit files not accessible via MTP you can activate Android Debug Bridge (ADB) on the phone, install the proper USB adb drivers and adb executables on your PC use adb for accessing files and folders using the commands adb pull adb push adb shell.
Those command give you direct access to the Android file system.

You could also use a .nomedia file in the folder you're trying to keep semi-hidden rather than a .folder folder name. Android software will generally ignore the folders with .nomedia files in them, but Windows will ignore that file.

@music2myear - Windows is already not showing the .private folder and the author cannot navigate to it within File Explorer so I don't see how using the  .nomedia folder will help especially if Windows cannot navigate to it.

3rd option: My android device has a file manager with SMB support (a standard samsung app) . One can create a share on the windows machine, browse to this share on the android device, and copy/paste the files .

@Ramhound, I am offering OP an alternative way of "hiding" folders on the Android while allowing them to be viewed over MTP connections. If OP does NOT use a .folder and instead uses a .nomedia file inside a regular folder, this may satisfy their needs.

I guess the issue is with how Android handles hidden files during MTP transfers. Unfortunately, MTP won’t show dot folders (.private) as it only exposes what Android allows.
As mentioned earlier, using ADB is your best option for full file system access. You’ll need to enable USB Debugging on your phone, install ADB tools on your PC, and use commands like adb pull to transfer files.
If ADB feels too technical, you can try third-party file managers directly on your Android that allow exploring hidden folders.
